# Receive push notifications in two different apps

Tags: quickblox

We are developing a coaching app service. It uses two different apps (in the store): one for coaches and one for customers.

We want to be able to use push notifications on both apps but the quickblox panel only allows to upload one certificate.

How can we go about using these two apps at the same time with quickblox? Is it maybe possible for two quickblox apps to talk to each other (each one with its own apns certificate) and if so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible on enterprise instances and this requires customisation.