# Can two different apps using Quickblox in iOS share a chat/dialog?

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am trying to write two apps that connect different kinds of users in both public group chats and private one-on-one chats using **Quickblox**. However, when I call `QBRequest dialogsForPage` I am getting completely different lists of public dialogs.

Does this require an enterprise instance, as mentioned in "[Receive push notifications in two different apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764164/receive-push-notifications-in-two-different-apps)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickblox doesn't prefer approach when users, dialogs etc. can be shared between different applications. We are not using this logic now and we will hardly use it later.

Comment: So it seems that QuickBlox does not support chat between two different applications. Twilio, PubNub and others *do* support this, just F.Y.I.